# What exactly are Level 2 quotes, and how are they related to the limit order book and "market depth"?

Tags: stock-markets, limit-order, quotes, market-making, level-2-quotes

I am trying to understand the definition of "Level 2 quotes" and their relationship to the "limit order book" and "market depth" ("depth of market"). I have noticed three possible competing definitions of "Level 2 quotes":

1. "Level 2 shows the best bid and ask at each trading venue". Example:

   - Level 2 quotes in TD Ameritrade's [thinkorswim trading platform](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/howToTos/thinkManual/Left-Sidebar/Level-II):

     > Level II is a thinkorswim gadget that displays best ask and bid prices for each of the exchanges making markets in stocks, options, and futures. [...]

     [image: Microsoft Level 2 quotes from thinkorswim (2020-08-06 10am)]

     Notice that each exchange is only listed once and that only the best bid and ask at each exchange is displayed.
2. "Level 2 shows the best bid and ask from each market maker". Examples:

   - Level 2 quotes on [OTC Markets](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/FSUMF/quote#level-2):

     [image: Fortescue Metals Group Ltd (FSUMF) Level 2 quotes from OTC Markets (at close on 2020-10-30)]

     Notice that each market maker is listed only once, and that only the best bid and ask from each market maker is displayed. Contrast with (1), which is a list of exchanges/ECNs rather than a list of market makers.
   - Level 2 quotes on NASDAQ:

     [image: Level 2 quotes from NASDAQ]
3. "Level 2 shows all bids and asks from every market maker". Example:

   - [NASDAQ Bookviewer with TotalView Data](https://data.nasdaq.com/BookViewer.aspx):

     [image: Full book from NASDAQ]

     Notice that every order from every market maker is shown. Contrast with (2), where only the best bid and ask from each market maker is shown.

Specific questions:

- When someone says "Level 2 quotes", do they mean (1), (2), or (3)? Is "Level 2 quotes" ambiguous?
- Which one is the "limit order book"? Is it (3) ["all the bids and asks from every market maker"]?
- Which one shows the "depth of market"? My guess would be (2) ["best bid and ask from each market maker"] and (3) ["all bids and asks from every market maker"]. It seems that "depth of market" is a loosely defined term.

I have read [Difference between limit order book and level 2 quotes](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/27547), but the answer there isn't really helpful besides mentioning that Level 2 has its origins in NASDAQ.

Comment: In addition, there is also "Market by Order" (MBO) and "Market by Price" (MBP) views of Level 2 data.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has answered, I will provide an incomplete answer based on what I have learned since the question was asked.

> When someone says "Level 2 quotes", do they mean (1), (2), or (3)? Is "Level 2 quotes" ambiguous?

According to the [Nasdaq Level 2 web page](https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=NQDS):

> Nasdaq Level 2 provides the top-of-file position for Nasdaq exchange participants.

According to the [Nasdaq Level 2 Specification](https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/technicalsupport/specifications/dataproducts/Level2Specification.pdf):

> Level 2 will provide only the best bid and ask position for each Nasdaq market participant registered in an issue.

> For the unattributed orders in the Nasdaq system, Level 2 will reflect only the top buy and sell prices under the MPID of “NSDQ”.

From this, we can conclude that conclude that "Level 2" is (2) ("Level 2 shows the best bid and ask from each market maker").

---

> how are [Level 2 quotes] related to the limit order book and “market depth”?

> Which one is the "limit order book"? Is it (3) ["all the bids and asks from every market maker"]?

> Which one shows the "depth of market"? My guess would be (2) ["best bid and ask from each market maker"] and (3) ["all bids and asks from every market maker"]. It seems that "depth of market" is a loosely defined term.

I don't know. I now know what "Level 2" is, but I still don't know what (1) and (3) are. If you know more, please write an answer.

Comment: See if this [Investopedia article](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/level3.asp#:~:text=A%20level%203%20quote%20allows%20a%20person%20to,ask%20price%20when%20they%20are%20bought%20and%20sold.) helps.